# Whether to use Flowable.create or Flowable.generate to make a file observable?

Tags: rx-java2

From https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)
the following snippet is provide to indicate correct usage for RXified file reading.

```java
Flowable<Integer> o = Flowable.generate(
     () -> new FileInputStream("data.bin"),
     (inputstream, output) -> {
         try {
             int byte = inputstream.read();
             if (byte < 0) {
                 output.onComplete();
             } else {
                 output.onNext(byte);
             }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             output.onError(ex);
         }
         return inputstream;
     },
     inputstream -> {
         try {
             inputstream.close();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             RxJavaHooks.onError(ex);
         }
     } 
);
```

I am doing the following

```java
public Flowable<byte[]> createFlowable(File file) {

    return Flowable.create(source -> {

        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin)) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                byte[] data = getMessageRawData(in);
                source.onNext(data);

            }
            source.onComplete();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            source.onError(ex);
        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

Does my code (uses try with resource) suffer from resource leakage if dispose is called mid way or what other side effects can be expected or is it just a different way of doing things?

Comment: Your approach suffers from buffer bloat and ignoring cancellation. You should try and modify the example `generate` instead.

Comment: Thank you  akarnokd. I have both implemented, the generate is the new one I added, I needed to understand what was the problem with the create. Now I need to somehow debug this and see how the buffer files up and what does the dispose do.